# Android Studio edit_Text

Tags: java, android, xml

Good day, I'm new here.

Program works perfectly when being run but I want to eliminate this

> ? com.example.myapplication.R.id.edit_text? (multiple choices...)

```
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.example.myapplication.MESSAGE";

    private EditText editText;

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(edit_text);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(edit_text);

        Button reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearMessageButton);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                editText.setText("");
            }
        }

        );

    }

}
```

XML:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Please enter text"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to set **R.id**

> In android programming,this is the particular reference of a UI
>   component that you have declared in your xml file. It is simply called
>   as an identifier of a UI.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);  

editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text); // Declare this Oncreate section
```

### Advice

At first go through https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

changed to like this

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `R.id.edit_text`. Because you are providing id of a xml element.

So, Your code will look like

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
```

Or simply press `Alt+Enter` to select appropriate option.